# blur face on a video file

Tags: video, editing, processing, visual-effects

does anyone know how can i blur a moving face on video file?

Comment: Do you have video editing software?

Comment: @Joe: I don't have any yet and that's why I need an advice from someone with experience

Comment: At least mention the OS.

Comment: The japonies movies with adult only content are blurying the intimate parts of the body. How they do that?

Comment: What a long "face" you have there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I bet you can do it in Adobe Premiere by applying a filter to part of the frame and moving that part around

Comment: I'm using Pinnacle Studio, but it is a lot of work for moving faces.