# Blur a moving area in a movie on Mac OS X

Tags: macos, video-editing, processing, visual-effects

Note, there's [already a question](https://superuser.com/questions/126812/blur-face-on-a-video-file) on this regard, but it's totally useless.

I need to blur, or put a small opaque mask to a moving object on a movie I took, I am using Mac OS X. Clearly, I don't want to shell out a lot of money for something so simple, so getting Adobe Premiere or similar software is a no go. I could however consider paying a small software (max 30 dollars) for this specific task.

Answer (score 2):

Another option is to use a tool like ffmpeg to extract all the frames from the video (as a jpeg images). You could then use any image editing software to blur the frames individually.  Then, could use ffmepg to reassemble all the frames back into a video. Yes, it's a very tedious way to do this, but it's free ;)

Answer (score 1):

If the object doesn't move too much then you can use [iMovie](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ko6GZhJh6tI). Your other option might be to use the trial version of Premiere if this is a one off thing you need to do.

Comment: These two following video tutorials could be helpful if you count to do it using iMovie: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9O8yRuA6W4I and https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uuUFlBfr660

Answer (score 1):

There is absolutely nothing simple about masking blurry objects in video unless you shot it in front of a chroma key backdrop. If it's not worth more than $30 then it's probably not going to happen unless you have a friend in film school who'll do it for free.

Comment: He doesn't want to "mask blurry objects", he wants to make a region of the video blurred or otherwise unreadable.  That's a pretty simple thing conceptually.

Answer (score 1):

Great video editing software for your Mac is [Final Cut Pro](http://apple.com/finalcutpro). If you don't want to pay for that you could probably do that in iMovie.